# find port number of USB port where GSM modem/Dongle is connected

Tags: java, usb, gsm

I am working on Java EE application where I want to send/receive messages to and from mobile number.

For this purpose I have used GSM Modem/Dongle.In which I have inserted SIM card from which I will transfer my messages to and from other mobiles.

So, to establish connection with GSM Modem I have to find USB port number where my GSM modem is connected.

So my question is how to find port number where my GSM modem is connected.

Comment: I think you'll need to get all connected usb devices and then find device you're interested in (GSM modem in given question). Since there're not thousands of usb hubs this won't be too heavy work. _Note:_ May be I am wrong and there's a way to get device directly.

Comment: @PLB you know how to find all connected usb devices?

Comment: You could use [`jUSB`](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/). But I've never used it.

Comment: i have tried much since you told me to use "jUSB" but i cant found port number, even i didn't got any solution to detect USB port using "jUSB".I have also searched on "JSR" ...so you know any other way..

Comment: @Aniket have you tried this one: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=80

Comment: @Aniket, sorry for late reply dear, well for Comm port you have to manually check Port number from Device Manager and select "Modem" init.

Comment: @Aniket, have you tried, what i said ?

Comment: @Lucifer i have checked it shows com 3 or com 6...

Comment: @Aniket, no, if you click on modem and then view its properties, it shows you only that modem's comm port, and you need to define that port into your code.

Comment: @Lucifer i have checked it shows me com4 but if i used com4 it can't print "SMS Sending....Port Found" as in case if i used com3 port number..

Comment: @Aniket, strange....it shouldn't show that.

Comment: @Lucifer is it possible to you to come down for chatting so i can better explain my work what actually i have done and where i am going wrong....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26428/discussion-between-lucifer-and-aniket)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ModemManager](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/man/1.0.0/mmcli.8.html) :

```
mmcli -L # list modems
mmcli -m <modem> # show modem
```

If you want to get the ports see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652831/435504).